# Timezone error in Django controller method

Tags: django, postgresql, psycopg2

I have the following controller method in my Django project:

```
def blog_detail(request, pk):

    post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)

    conn = psycopg.connect(
        host="localhost",
        dbname="myproject2",
        user="postgres",
        password=""
    )

    from django.db import connections
    connections['default'].connection = conn

    form = comment_form()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = comment_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = Comments(
                author=form.cleaned_data["author"],
                body=form.cleaned_data["body"],
                post=post
            )
            comment.save()

    comments = Comments.objects.filter(post=post)
    context = {
        "post": post,
        "comments": comments,
        "form": form
    }
    return render(request, "blog_detail.html", context)
```

When I load the view associated with this controller I get:

".../base.py", line 336, in create_cursor
if self.timezone != tzloader.timezone:
AttributeError: type object 'TimestamptzLoader' has no attribute 'timezone'

The model looks like:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category', related_name='posts')

class Comments(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    body = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey('Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

My settings file has:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_TZ = True
```

My postgresql.conf file had timezone set to Europe/London so I set that to UTC but I got the same error.

Comment: Why would you create connection inside of view? Use proper https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/databases/#postgresql-connection-settings and  database routing. Also which database version and psycopg version do you use

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem with the following code in the controller:

```
from django.db.backends.postgresql.psycopg_any import register_tzloader 
register_tzloader("UTC", conn)
```